# Клиент-сервер на разных языках

Tags: java, c#, клиент-сервер

Можно ли сделать сервер на c#, а клиент на java?

Comment: Можно. Продумайте протокол и стройте взаимодействие с использованием этого протокола.

Comment: @Alexandr, а что значит "продумать протокол". Если на обеих сторонах использовать tcp/ip?

Comment: В ответе ниже тоже немного про это сказано: "использовать общий формат взаимодействия". На нижнем уровне у вас все равно будет или tcp/ip или udp, но эти протоколы ответственны за то чтобы передавать поток байтов между клиентом и сервером. Вам нужно продумать более высокоуровневые вопросы, например, какими командами будут обмениваться клиент и сервер, как вы их будете кодировать, как вы для этих команд будете передавать дополнительные параметры, как вы будете понимать что параметры кончились и началась новая команда и так далее. Примеры высокоуровневых протоколов: HTTP, SOAP, XMPP,

Comment: @Alexandr, взаимодействие команд я уже написал. Сделал просто чтобы клиент передавал серверу строку разделенную `"|"` и сервер разделял строку на массив строк регексом. Первый элемент - команда, остальные агрументы. После обработки, сервер отправляет ObjectOutputStream объект и клиент его читает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно можно. Почему нет?

Сервер и клиент в общем случае могут быть написаны на любом подходящем языке программирования.

Единственное требование они должны использовать,скажем так, общий формат взаимодействия. Достигается это с помощью таких вещей как, например, TCP, REST, SOAP.